# Custom img in the view in odoo 16

Tags: image, view, odoo-16

odoo 16.0 community

I have a model with Guid from other system, how can I provide link on the view to link it?
My model:

```
class Partners(models.Model):
  _inherit = "res.partner"
  ktc_guid=fields.Char()
  code=fields.Char()
```

My view:

```
<record id="res_partner_view_form" model="ir.ui.view">
   <field name="name">res.partner.form.inherit</field>
   <field name="model">res.partner</field>
   <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form"/>
   <field name="arch" type="xml">
      <xpath expr="//div[hasclass('oe_title')]" position="after">
          <div>
            <img t-attr-src="https:/.../{ktc_guid}" />
          </div>
      </xpath>
   </field>
</record>
```

But ktc_guid is undefined always

Answer (score 0):

Try this change the image field name to your desired image field name and you are good to go.

```
image = fields.Binary(string="Image", compute='_compute_image_url')
image_url = fields.Char(string='Image URL')

@api.depends('image_url')
def _compute_image_url(self):
    """ function to load image from URL """
    image = False
    if self.image_url:
        image = base64.b64encode(requests.get(self.image_url).content)
    self.image = image
```